# mklink, target replacement denied in Visual Studio 2010 (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mklink

mklink behaves very strangely on the following accounts:

1. it requires command.exe run as Administrator (what for?), although I am admin user already
2. if I have a symlink app.exe -> app.20.21.exe then Visual Srudio 2010 refuses first to compile to app.20.21.exe (Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\zTest2.exe" to "..............\fl\bin\app.20.21.exe". Access to the path '..............\fl\bin\app.20.21.exe' is denied)

HOWEVER, if you wait for a few minutes (doing nothing), then by magic VS compiles the same file to the previously denied target OK!

Any remedies for that? (besides running everything as Administrator) Any decent documentation on mklink?

Answer (score 0):

You must be having experience with file deletion????

Sometimes, it happens we try deleting a file which is being used by other process and in result we get a message

> Access Denied!!

Same thing happens in this case, when some process is already working on your application and the same time you want to perform a clean/delete operation on it, obviously it will fail because it is under a lock state and for avoiding data corruption OS wont allow any write transaction on resource until the previous task is done.

So its better to look out for the reason that why the compilation is going slow and resources remain under lock state.Otherwise second option is to wait for some time till VS finishes.